# Magento 2.3 inventory index gives The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again

Tags: magento2.3, indexing, inventory, msi

The inventory index doesn't get re-indexed, it gives this message:

> The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again.

In other questions I found that there could be products without SKU, but there aren't any in my database.

I have [read here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/) that the re-indexation process generates a table with virtual stock based (among others) on quantity from assigned stocks.
Now I found that there are SKU's in my inventory source (default source) for items I deleted, so products with these SKU's do not exist. Could this cause this issue?

If this causes the issue, what should I delete/update? I do not know in what table this inventory is stored. Or if there are any other sources/tables that need these items deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently we experienced this very issue too. Solution in our case was making sure the `inventory_source_item` MySQL table does not contain any defunct SKU's. To lookup corrupted records in said table, try next MySQL query:

```
SELECT isi.* FROM inventory_source_item isi LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe ON isi.sku = cpe.sku WHERE cpe.sku IS NULL;
```

Removing the resulting rows had the inventory indexer working again.

Seems like a foreign key on the SKU (within the `inventory_source_item` table, pointing to `catalog_product_entity`) is lacking. Not sure if such key is missing on purpose, but adding one with `ON DELETE CASCADE` should prevent the error message from occurring again. Although it is advised to have this confirmed by Magento over a GitHub issue / report. [Could not find any related tickets](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20inventory_source_item%20is%3Aopen) at the moment, so this is still to be reported.

Answer (score 0):

For me the `cataloginventory_stock_item` & `quote_item` tables were the offending ones here. Somehow customers with old carts were able to checkout with products that didn't exist. Something to do with their old Magento 1 migration to Magento 2 I think. I tweaked the above query from @Ward like so:

`cataloginventory_stock_item`

```
DELETE FROM cataloginventory_stock_item WHERE product_id IN(
        SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT isi.product_id FROM cataloginventory_stock_item isi
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe ON isi.product_id = cpe.entity_id
                WHERE cpe.entity_id IS NULL
       ) AS p
);
```

`quote_item`

```
DELETE FROM quote_item WHERE product_id IN(
        SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT isi.product_id FROM quote_item isi
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe ON isi.product_id = cpe.entity_id
                WHERE cpe.entity_id IS NULL
        ) AS p
);
```